# Почему код для блокировки клавиатуры не работает на Windows 7?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, hook

Хочу свою программу для блокировки экрана. [Вот взял код для блокировки клавиатуры](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/block_system_part.html)

```
unit mklu;

interface

uses
  Windows;

var
  m_OldMHook: HHook = 0;
  k_OldKBHook: HHook = 0;

function KbHook(code: Integer; wparam: Word; lparam: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall;
procedure KeyBoardOn;
procedure KeyBoardOff;
function MouseHook(code: Integer; wparam: Word; lparam: LongInt): LongInt;
  stdcall;
procedure MOUSEON;
procedure MouseOff;

implementation

function KbHook(code: Integer; wparam: Word; lparam: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall;
begin
  if code < 0 then
    Result := CallNextHookEx(k_oldKbHook, code, wparam, lparam)
  else
    Result := 1;
end;

// включение клавы

procedure KeyBoardOn;
begin
  if k_OldKbHook <> 0 then
  begin
    UnHookWindowshookEx(k_OldKbHook);
    k_OldKbHook := 0;
  end;
end;

// выключение клавы

procedure KeyBoardOff;
begin
  k_OldKbHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, @KbHook, HInstance, 0);
end;

function MouseHook(code: Integer; wparam: Word; lparam: LongInt): LongInt;
  stdcall;
begin
  if code < 0 then
    Result := CallNextHookEx(m_oldMHook, code, wparam, lparam)
  else
    Result := 1;
end;

// включение мышки

procedure MOUSEON;
begin
  if m_OldMHook <> 0 then
  begin
    UnHookWindowshookEx(m_OldMHook);
    m_OldMHook := 0;
  end;
end;

// выключение мышки

procedure MouseOff;
begin
  m_OldMHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, @MOUSEHook, HInstance, 0);
end;

end.
Пример использования:

uses mklu;

{блокировка(LockIt = true) или разблокировка(LockIt= False) клавы}

procedure LockUnlockKeyboard(LockIt: Boolean);
begin
  if LockIt then
    KeyBoardOFF
  else
    KeyBoardOn;
end;

{блокировка(LockIt = true) или разблокировка(LockIt= False) мышки}

procedure LockUnlockMouse(LockIt: Boolean);
begin
  if LockIt then
    MouseOff
  else
    MouseOn;
end;
```

работает отлично на Windows XP, а на Windows 7 почему то не пашет...  В чем проблема?

Comment: Честно говоря, подробностей не помню, давно развлекался, но я не смотрел на code вообще, и всегда возвращал -1 из хука. Этот блокировщик у меня до сих пор работает, и под 7. Может раскопаю исходники, если интересно, но там C.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется в Win 7 мешает контроль учетных записей(UAC)
Отключи его, и приложение запускай от имени администратора

Comment: Да я уже понял, что в нем проблема. Но UAC выключать не вариант... Тут вычитал, что надо сделать манифест... НО вот как? Увидел во тут, но как-то ничего не понятно, что надо делать... (http://www.vmpsoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=167)